# Prestashop frontpage stylesheet doesn't load after migrating

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with Presta after migrating. I've migrate it from live server to localhost, everything was ok.

But now when I migrate it from localhost to live server (copy files, and import db) front office stylesheets doesn't load. I've changed domain, clear cache, generate new robots file, physical_uri, turn on and off cache and nothing changed. In backoffice everything works fine.

Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the urls and site folder in the ps_shop_url table?

Regards